# a value of color can't be assigned to a type color

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am getting an error how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `Colors.indigo[900]` with `Colors.indigo[900]!`:

```dart
Color bgColor = data['isDayTime'] ? Colors.blue : Colors.indigo[900]!;
```

`Color.indigo` is a `MaterialColor` and the returned type of the operator `[]` on a `MaterialColor` is `Color?`. It means it can return a `Color`, but also `null`.

If you know that `Colors.indigo[900]` is not `null`. Then you can use the null check operator (`!`) to tell dart that you know the variable `Colors? Colors.indigo[900]` is not `null` and it is in fact a `Color`.